# Regular Expression Clarification?

Tags: python, regex, text-extraction

If I have a string that contains several instances of text that looks like this:

"img": "/static/thumbs/1607.02533v4.pdf.jpg"

What would the regular expression look like to extract this part:

1607.02533v4.pdf

Tried something like this: `re.findall(r'(?<=thumbs/)(.*)(?=.jpg)')` to get the text between but it doesn't seem to be working.

Edit: Figured out the problem. The match was greedy, needed to add a ? after .*

`re.findall(r'(?<=thumbs/)(.*?)(?=.jpg)')`

Comment: You're missing an escape character after thumbs. It should be `(?<=thumbs\/)(.*)(?=.jpg)`. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/DeFyrK/1)

Comment: @WStokvis It should definitely not be `.*`.

Comment: Is this string JSON?

Comment: You could also try with this: `/thumbs/(.*?).jpg`

Comment: If you want to use a regex, it should be [`re.findall(r'"img"\s*:\s*"[^"]*/([^"]*)\.jpg"', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/srTxTU/1) but it is advisable to first use `json` module to get the right *plain texts* first and then extract the values you need easier.

Comment: @game0ver that worked

Comment: @JohnFisher Nice, congrats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example assuming the files all have the same naming convention:

```
import re
s = '''
"img": "/static/thumbs/1607.02533v1.pdf.jpg"
"img": "/static/thumbs/1608.02533v2.pdf.jpg"
"img": "/static/thumbs/1609.02533v3.pdf.jpg"
"img": "/static/thumbs/1610.02533v4.pdf.jpg"
'''
re.findall(r'thumbs/([0-9.a-z]+.pdf)', s)
```

output:

```
['1607.02533v1.pdf', '1608.02533v2.pdf', '1609.02533v3.pdf', '1610.02533v4.pdf']
```

explanation:

```
thumbs/([0-9.a-z]+.pdf)
```

starts with `thumbs/`
has a group with 1 or more characters `0-9` a `.` and `a-z` and ends with `.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

**Execute 1607.02533v4.pdf**

*For C# ASP.NET 2.0 - 4.7.2, .NET Core, C++, Delphi :*

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+v[0-9]+\.\w{3}
```

**Execute 1607.02533v4**

*For C# ASP.NET 2.0 - 4.7.2, .NET Core, C++, Delphi :*

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+v[0-9]+
```

*Java 8, Javascript, MySQL, Orqcle 11gR2 & 12c, PHP 7.0.4 - 4.1.17, Visual Basic 6, Python 2.7, Python 3.6, Ruby 2.4 - 2.5, VBScript :*

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+v
```

Here [online RegEx tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

[image: Result]